# Java phone Number format regex

Tags: java, regex, match

I am wanting to create a regex for the following number formats:
+XXXXXXXXXX. +1(XXX)xxxxxx, +x(xxx)-xxx-xxxx, xxx-xxx-xxxx, xxx-xxxx, and Phone Number:,Phone:,Tel: with all the above formats. All with the output of xxxxxxxxxx

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
  public static String getPhoneNumber() // returns the phone number formatted as a sequence of digits
    {

        String regex = "^\\(?([0-9]{3})\\)?[-.\\s]?([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]{4})(?:Tel:)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) 
        {
              //if phone number format includes -, . , spaces, + sign in front
              if (line.matches("[+]?\\d?[- .]?(\\([0-9]\\d{2}\\)|[0-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$")) {
                phoneNumber = line.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").replace("-", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
                        .replace("+", "");

              }
              else
              {
                  getEmailAddress();
              }
                  }
        //System.out.println(phoneNumber);
        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

Comment: The `.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")` should remove **all** non-digit characters and therefore the additional `replace()` methods are not required (note: there is no dot in the regex).

Comment: Looks like you've got a reasonable start.  What difficulty are you having?

Comment: The trouble is I have it recognizing the numbers in the different formats stated above. Except if there is a "Tel:" or anything like that before the string I cant figure out how to get it to accept that it is a phone number still. It should be able to figure out that I was to use the line for a phone number and not something labeled as a fax.

Comment: Can you show some sample strings

Comment: Sample input Strings include: +111-111-1111, Tel: 111-111-1111, Phone Number: (111)-111-1111 etc..

Comment: Perhaps try something like this: `if (line.toLowerCase().matches("(.*?phone number:.*)|(.*?phone:.*)|(.*?ph:.*)|(.*?tel:.*)")) { line = line.replaceAll("[^\\d]",""); }`.

Comment: Why is this question tagged under `design-patterns` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regex `^(?:(?:Tel|Phone Number|Phone): )?(\+?\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]\d{3}[-. ]\d{4})$`.

This will match the phone numbers with the keywords `Phone`,`Tel` or `Phone Number` and not with others.

Capture group `$1` to get the phone number.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/JG4bsP/1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove all non-digits, so just do that. To select lines, match those that have (at least) 10 digits:

```
if (line.matches("(\\D*\\d){10}.*"))) {
    phoneNumber = line.replaceAll("\\D", "");
}
```

is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

String pattern = "\d{10}|(?:\d{3}-){2}\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-?\d{4}";